# Is there a WPF Output Monitor Control like the Visual Studio Debug Output

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, wpf-controls

I am trying to add a output monitor to my WPF application.
A read only monitor similar to the debug output in visual studio.

Is there a WPF control which already provides the functionality I need?
Or is there a way I could reuse the control from Visual Studio?

Currently I'm using a standard TextBox backed by a StringBuilder. Updates go to the StringBuilder while the TextBox gets the newest string every 200ms.

My problem is that this gets really slow as the output string gets longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the RichTextBox control to output the data.

In this sample I had no problem with performance at all.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private int counter = 0;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded+=OnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        {
            AddLine(counter++ + ": Initial data");
        }

        var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 200);
        timer.Tick += TimerOnTick;
        timer.IsEnabled = true;
    }

    private void TimerOnTick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        AddLine(counter++ + ": Random text");
    }

    public void AddLine(string text)
    {
        outputBox.AppendText(text);
        outputBox.AppendText("\u2028"); // Linebreak, not paragraph break
        outputBox.ScrollToEnd();
    }
}
```

And XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <RichTextBox x:Name="outputBox"
                     VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                     HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                     IsReadOnly="True">
            <FlowDocument/>
        </RichTextBox>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And it's probably easy to extend it. If the scroll position is not at the end, do not Scroll to the end, for example, so that you can view old data while the text box is still updating.

Comment: I'm using MVVM pattern and DataBinding so my ViewModel which gets the data has no way of directly calling the AppendText method of the RichTextBox.
But I will try to get around that. Maybe I can use a DependencyProperty.

Comment: Hm.. How about create an event in your ViewModel that your View listens to, and calls AddLine() from there? If not, you could try to bind to the Document, but I'm not exactly sure what the best way to add a line of text that way is. (take note, binding to Document is hard)

Comment: I used the RichTextBox approach and implemented my own writer which writes to a FlowDocument. The performance is quite good.

Sorry for the long wait. I was on holiday for quite some time.

Comment: I ended up abandoning this solution due to performance issues and being harder to extend then this solution hinted. I had performance issues both trying to do a lot of line appends (witch btw I had to separate using new lines, to be able to copy the output to notepad), and also while trying to not autoscroll if the cursor was not on the last line. It's really complicated to determine the line number on a ritchtextbox. Ended up using a simple textbox (which also has append line), and a checkbox to enable/disable autoscroll.

Comment: Hi @Akselk thanks for the code. There is one problem, when I copy the text from the output the linebreak is not copied along making it hard to read. If I replace "\u2028" with \n it works fine though but the output displays it in two lines instead of one.